# T-sql comparing results of linked server query with local query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to compare the results of a linked server query with a local query.  What I am try to do is find out what Logins exist on one server but not the other.  Just windows auth accounts is fine for now.

My current query is

```
Select name 
from [linkedServer].master.[sys].[server_principals]  
Where name not in ('Select name from sys.server_principals')
```

What I get back is the result of the linked server query only with the where ignored. How do I go about comparing the results of the two?

Comment: Why is it that you think the results are actually incorrect?

Comment: @DanBracuk - they clearly will be as they are basically doing `Select name from [linkedServer].master.[sys].[server_principals]  Where name  <> 'select ...'` - the single quotes is a string not a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `not exists`. Second, I think your single quotes are wrong:

```
select sp.name
from [linkedServer].master.[sys].[server_principals] sp
where not exists (select 1
                  from sys.server_principals sp2
                  where sp2.name = sp.name
                 );
```

I strongly recommend that you get in the habit of using `not exists` with a subquery rather than `not in`, because `not in` returns no row if *any* value from the subquery is `NULL`.  That is usually not desirable behavior.

Comment: There is always more than one way to accomplish something and in this case, I would lean towards an `except` query.

Comment: Changed it except as suggested.